# TopLayoutGuide and NavigationBar ShadowImage, Xamarin, iOS, Autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want to align view right under NavigationBar on my view.
I use reference to TopLayoutGuide to achieve this.
[image]
Height of FixedHeaderView is set to 21.
However, when I run the app, FixedHeaderView is exactly 1 pixel (on retina device) under NavigationBar.
It seems like the shadow image (bottom border of NavigationBar) is taking this 1 pixel.

Here is a measure of screenshot from iOS Simulator (5s, 8.1)
[image]

In order to fix that, I had to write this code in my ViewController

```
HeaderTopConstraint.Constant = 0.5f;
```

**Question is**: how do I take this 0.5/1 pixel into account using just constraints?
I don't want to write this code on all views I plan to use similar layout.

Why doesn't TopLayoutGuide take care of this 0.5/1 pixel?